# Best way to store X clicks/days in MySQL

Tags: mysql, storage

I want to store my users clicks from the last 10 days in my database.

I have heard that storing it like this: "4;3;1;4;5;3;7;2;6;3" is a really bad idea, and it breaks the rules.

But, what better way is there to store clicks for this many days? For me, it would be insane to create 10 columns with each day clicks.

Please advice.

Comment: What about days 10+? History? Archive? Delete?

Comment: I will only store from the last 10 days. Cronjob will upate the stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd store then in a table like this

```
userkey (PK, FK)
date (PK)
clicks
```

At some point, you'll be asked for "last 30 days" or "last year"

And it makes maintenance easier of managing 10 columns or trying to roll values